# Event to show list when clicking on an option

Tags: python, wxglade

How can I display the list on the right pane when clicking on an item in the left pane? For example, as per the code, if I click on option A in the left pane, it displays one list but if I click on the B option, it display another list on the right pane.

Moreover, I also want to double click on the row in the right pane to open a new modal window. I would also like the window in max size when starting.

```
import wx
import sys

# Define the tab content as classes:
class TabOne(wx.Panel):
def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

    self.SetSize((400, 100))
    self.window_1 = wx.SplitterWindow(self, wx.ID_ANY)



    self.tree = wx.TreeCtrl(self.window_1, style=wx.TR_DEFAULT_STYLE | 
    wx.TR_EDIT_LABELS)

    root = self.tree.AddRoot("Server")


    letters = []
    il = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"]
    ila = ["x","y","z"]


    for letter in il:
        item = self.tree.AppendItem(root, letter)
        if letter == "C":
            for ila1 in ila:
                sub_item = self.tree.AppendItem(item, ila1)


    self.window_1_pane_2 = wx.Panel(self.window_1, wx.ID_ANY)


    players = [('R1', '10', '20'), ('R2', '30', '40'), 
               ('R3', '50', '60'), ('R4', '70', '80'), 
               ('R5', '90', '99')]

    self.list = wx.ListCtrl(self.window_1_pane_2, -1, style = 
    wx.LC_REPORT) 
    self.list.InsertColumn(0, 'Col1', width = 100) 
    self.list.InsertColumn(1, 'Col2', wx.LIST_FORMAT_RIGHT, 100) 
    self.list.InsertColumn(2, 'Col3', wx.LIST_FORMAT_RIGHT, 100) 

    for i in players: 
       index = self.list.InsertItem(sys.maxsize, i[0]) 
       self.list.SetItem(index, 1, i[1]) 
       self.list.SetItem(index, 2, i[2]) 


    self.window_1.SetMinimumPaneSize(20)


    sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer_4 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    sizer_4.Add(self.list,1,wx.EXPAND)
    self.window_1_pane_2.SetSizer(sizer_4)
    self.window_1.SplitVertically(self.tree, self.window_1_pane_2)
    sizer_1.Add(self.window_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
    self.SetSizer(sizer_1)


def AddTreeNodes(self, parentItem, items):
    for item in items:
        if type(item) == str:
            newItem = self.tree.AppendItem(parentItem, item)
            self.tree.SetItemData(newItem, None)

        else:
            newItem = self.tree.AppendItem(parentItem, item[0])
            self.tree.SetItemPyData(newItem, None)

            self.tree.SetItemImage(newItem, self.fldropenidx,wx.TreeItemIcon_Expanded)

            self.AddTreeNodes(newItem, item[1])






   class TabTwo(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
    t = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "This is the second tab", (20,20))

class TabThree(wx.Panel):
def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
    t = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "This is the third tab", (20,20))

class TabFour(wx.Panel):
def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
    t = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "This is the last tab", (20,20))


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="wxPython tabs example 
@pythonspot.com")

    # Create a panel and notebook (tabs holder)
    p = wx.Panel(self)
    nb = wx.Notebook(p)

    # Create the tab windows
    tab1 = TabOne(nb)
    tab2 = TabTwo(nb)
    tab3 = TabThree(nb)
    tab4 = TabFour(nb)

    # Add the windows to tabs and name them.
    nb.AddPage(tab1, "Tab 1")
    nb.AddPage(tab2, "Tab 2")
    nb.AddPage(tab3, "Tab 3")
    nb.AddPage(tab4, "Tab 4")

    # Set noteboook in a sizer to create the layout
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
    sizer.Add(nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
    p.SetSizer(sizer)





if __name__ == "__main__":
app = wx.App(redirect=True)
MainFrame().Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Your code has some indentation problems. If you fix them you will have better chances of getting an answer.